# How elasticsearch store field and name into index?

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch, lucene

[Here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/inverted-index.html) is description about mapping between terms and documents. But what if I need to search document in elastice by one field value? How does elasticsearch filter values for concrete fields from all terms?

Comment: What do you mean by "one field value"?

Comment: `{"oneField":"oneValue", "secondField":"secondValue"}`. According to documentation documents index handle matching to `oneValue` or `secondValue`, but how it determine what value correspond to what field.

Comment: A bit confused.  Are you asking about how you would have different values in different fields when using elasticsearch?  Or implementation details on how Lucene stores and searches that information?

Comment: The first point, vecause documetation says only about documents and calue, not fields.